# Would it be best to scale fewer larger instances, or more smaller instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

what will be the best option to choose b/w less number of large instances or more number of the small instance when the performance is concerned, as the cloudwatch (load balancing and scaling) will be used if the traffic floods on the servers.

Answer (score 3):

**`AWS is all about ELASTICITY`**

There is no need to provision large instances when not needed and burn out money. 
There can be many instances when your CPU on one goes high and the next large instance you created remains under-utilized.

You should have medium instances to small w.r.t the tier you require (Memory Intensive, CPU, or Network) and scale those instances with properly written policies.

As long as the userdata, ami is stable you can spawn many instances within minutes making sure you are not spending way too much and saving every Penny.

**SCALE WHEN NEEDED HORIZONTALLY**

Answer (score 1):

This is heavily dependent on your application.

I agree with Faisal Nizam's intuition of favoring horizontal scaling. However, there are many applications that will not run very well on small instances.

For example, [Elastic recommends](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html) to have Elasticsearch cluster nodes with 64GB of RAM. Similar reasoning can be applied to many other data related applications, where it can be beneficial if a single instance is able to keep large data chunks in memory.

I would recommend to find the ideal instance size for your application, and from there scale horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Each EC2 has also some overhead, so you need to find a balance between large & costly instances vs. a lot and small instances with overhead.

Answer (score 0):

(As of today) To vertically scale up/scale down an EC2 server, it needs to be shut down and spun back up - something to keep in mind before deciding to go for it.